# Mathmode: Treating binary operators as standalone symbols for spacing purposes

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

I'd like to use symbol `\sim` as the name of a set, and write expressions such as `$x \in \sim$`. But `\sim` is treated by TeX as a relation symbol and as a result the spacing around `\in` isn't quite right. Is there a way to signal to TeX that I'm using `\sim` as a standalone symbol so that it adjusts the spacing accordingly? Or am I better off adjusting the spacing manually?

Comment: Like `\mathord{\sim}`? Best done in a macro, I guess.

Comment: Besides Mickes suggestions you also should be able to use `{\sim}` (AFAIR). But do make a macro for it. This is especially important when you're using a syntax where a symbol can now mean two or more things. The prime example is `|` which can mean so many things in math. Whenever I edit manuscripts, it is not allowed to have any `|` in the body of the text. They should be replaced by a more contextually precise macro.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure your readers will be happy, but you're the judge.

The main point is that with `\mathord\sim` you make `\sim` into an ordinary atom, just like a standard letter. This can be shortened to `{\sim}`.

However, it's better to define a personal command for it, particularly if you also use `\sim` in its binary relation nature. And, maybe, after pondering the usage as an ordinary symbol you decide to change the appearance. Having your typescript full of `{\sim}` would require a very tedious job of “find and replace”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\simset}{\mathord\sim}

\begin{document}

$x\in\simset$

$x\sim y$

\end{document}
```

[image]